"IDA Pro Error: 'No connection could be made' when attaching to process on rooted Android device"
I am attempting to perform dynamic analysis on an Android application using IDA Pro.
I have connected my rooted phone via a USB cable and executed the necessary commands through the command prompt.
I have also configured the settings in IDA, including the host name and port.However, when I click on "Attach to Process," I receive the following error message: "connect: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. When connecting 127.0.0.1:23946."
How can I resolve this issue?

You should include the commands you execute for establishing the connection (edit your question and add them there). Do you use the Ida Android server or common gdb server on device?
